# WebDriver: Why doesn’t send_keys work after find_element_by_xpath?

Tags: python, text, selenium, filter, webdriver

I want to test a text filter with Webdriver (for Python, Chrome & Firefox). On the web page is a list of names and an input field. When the user types text the list of names is filtered, names wich don't contain the typed text will be hidden. When the user presses Enter/Return the best matching name will be copied to another input field. First I type the text (have to use XPath):

```
textbox = browser.find_element_by_xpath(pathToInputField)
textbox.send_keys(text)
```

Then the list is checked (slightly simplified):

```
for name in names:
    xpath = "//div[contains(text(), '{0}')]".format(name)
    elmIsDisplayed = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).is_displayed()
    if (text in name):
       self.assertTrue(elmIsDisplayed)
    else:
       self.assertFalse(elmIsDisplayed)
```

Up to this point it works fine. After that I try to hit Enter/Return:

```
textbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

But the input field (accessed by textbox or find_element_by_xpath) won't get any key (neither Return nor any other char). When I remove the

```
find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

for the checking of names the correct name is copied and all works. So it seems that the xpath search for another element prevents the second send_keys(). Do I miss some detail here or is this a bug?

Comment: Is Selenium reporting any errors or warnings for the second `send_keys` call?

Comment: chromedriver log for the second send_key: [420.588][FINE]:    Command received (/session/27e363d56a1244183e94f109af1a2389/element/:wdc:1352473329737/value) with params {
   "id": ":wdc:1352473329737",
   "sessionId": "27e363d56a1244183e94f109af1a2389",
   "value": [ "\uE006" ]
}
Can't see any "element not found" message, the test just fails when the second input field is empty.

Comment: This might be stupid obvious, but did you import `Keys`? You know, `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

Comment: What's the log for the first?  Make sure the id param is actually the same.

Comment: IDs for send_keys in chromedriver log are equal.

Comment: is there a reason why you're using xpath?  whats the xpath?  you may be able to at least try to recreate it as a css selector and try that way, and if it works then it's probably a bug.  but if it still doesn't work it would be helpful to post the code here

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, could you try to use javascript instead of send_keys, like this:

```
js_code = """
    var eventName = "keypress";
    var keycode = 13;
    var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    evt.initKeyboardEvent(eventName, true, true, window, false, false, false, false, keycode, keycode);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
"""
textbox.evaluateJavaScript(js_code)
```

Comment: I tried to trigger the key event with Javascript, it also failed.